# How would I print the ID of anchor tag to the console when it is clicked using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Would a button need to be used to do this rather than an Anchor Tag? I made attempt at a function but I'm relatively new to jquery and haven't made much progress figuring this out.

```
<nav>
<a href="#" id="home" class="test" onclick="addClickListener()">HOME</a>
<a href="#" id="about" class="test" onclick="addClickListener()" >  ABOUT</a>
<a href="#" id="services" class="test" onclick="addClickListener()">SERVICES</a>
<a href="#" id="photos" class="test" onclick="addClickListener()">PHOTOS</a>
<a href="#" id="rentals" class="test" onclick="addClickListener()">RENTALS</a>
</nav>
```

JQUERY:

```
function addClickListener(){
$("a").click(function(e) {
    console.log("click " + e.currentTarget.id);
});}
```

Would I need to store it in a variable and then use a separate function to log the variable? I have spent an hour looking at similar questions on something that seems so simple.

Comment: What more would you like me to share? I've never asked a question here but I must have done something wrong if I am -2 already. I have no experience with web outside of some CSS so this may seem obvious but my apologies.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - some people here are a bit impatient and downvote quickly.  For future reference, please read our [ask] page for hints on how to write great questions as they tend to get great answers from the community.

Comment: I added an answer explaining what the code does

Comment: Thank you to everyone that answered all of the code in every answer achieves the same goal and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of the below code. Don't write click event inside function call.

```
<nav>
<a href="#" id="home" class="test" onclick="addClickListener()">HOME</a>
<a href="#" id="about" class="test" onclick="addClickListener()" >  ABOUT</a>
<a href="#" id="services" class="test" onclick="addClickListener()">SERVICES</a>
<a href="#" id="photos" class="test" onclick="addClickListener()">PHOTOS</a>
<a href="#" id="rentals" class="test" onclick="addClickListener()">RENTALS</a>
</nav>

function addClickListener(){
    console.log("click " + this.id);
}


OR




<nav>
<a href="#" id="home" class="test" >HOME</a>
<a href="#" id="about" class="test"  >  ABOUT</a>
<a href="#" id="services" class="test" >SERVICES</a>
<a href="#" id="photos" class="test" >PHOTOS</a>
<a href="#" id="rentals" class="test" >RENTALS</a>
</nav>

$("a").click(function(e) {
    console.log("click " + this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <nav>
  <a href="#" id="home" class="test">HOME</a> 
  <a href="#" id="about" class="test">  ABOUT</a>
  <a href="#" id="services" class="test">SERVICES</a>
  <a href="#" id="photos" class="test">PHOTOS</a>
  <a href="#" id="rentals" class="test">RENTALS</a>
 </nav>



 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(event) {
  console.log("click " + event.target.id);
 });
 });
```

Comment: While this answer may address the issue, it's good practice to explain what the code does for the benefit of the OP and others in the community

Answer (score 0):

You can try using plain old JavaScript.  In this case, you could pass the parameter `this` to the function call (in this case it refers to the element being clicked on.

```
<a href="#" id="home" class="test" onclick="addClickListener(this)">HOME</a>
```

Also, in the function definition, the parameter is the DOM object of the anchor tag, so you can retrieve its properties like this

```
function addClickListener(anchorObj){
  console.log( anchorObj.id );
}
```

See running demo below:

```js
function addClickListener(anchorObj){
  console.log( anchorObj.id );
}
```

```html
   
<nav>
  <a href="#" id="home" class="test" onclick="addClickListener(this)">HOME</a>
  <a href="#" id="about" class="test" onclick="addClickListener(this)">  ABOUT</a>
  <a href="#" id="services" class="test" onclick="addClickListener(this)">SERVICES</a>
  <a href="#" id="photos" class="test" onclick="addClickListener(this)">PHOTOS</a>
  <a href="#" id="rentals" class="test" onclick="addClickListener(this)">RENTALS</a>
</nav>
```

**However**, since you asked how to do it in JQuery.  I will show you this one as well.

The code below is binding the onclick event listener to all the anchor tags in the document.

```
$('a').on('click', function() {...}
```

Let me know if you need clarification on what the code does.

```js
// wrap your definition in this to ensure the document is ready first
$(function() {
  // bind an event listener to the anchor tags
  $('a').on('click', function() {
    // this refers to the anchor tag clicked on.
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <a href="#" id="home" class="test">HOME</a>
  <a href="#" id="about" class="test">ABOUT</a>
  <a href="#" id="services" class="test">SERVICES</a>
  <a href="#" id="photos" class="test">PHOTOS</a>
  <a href="#" id="rentals" class="test">RENTALS</a>
</nav>
```